# Is there a standard directory to keep software projects shared by multiple users?

Tags: directory-structure

When working on source code (for example, a python project) that needs to be accessed by multiple users, is there a standard place to keep those projects?

I found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1157) which suggests `/usr/local/` for installing applications, but I'm not sure that would be an appropriate place to keep source code for programming projects in progress.

Comment: I think the standard place now is Github

Comment: But any local directory with 77x permissions and anyone:group ownership will work, assuming everyone who wants to work on it is in the right group

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard dir assigned in the FHS for this purpose, but you could create a subdir in `/opt`. Just assign it mode 770 and put the users in the appropriate group.

However, I **highly** recommend that for this kind of activity you install a revision control system such as `git`. In this way git will take care of the source repo, and each developer will work in their private repo in their homedir.

Comment: I don't think `/opt` is the right choice. According `FHS` it should be somewhere below `/var/` or `/srv/`. Regardless whether you run a `git` or other VCS server or just a simple shared directory.  Also one user could administrate such shared directory within his own $HOME without involving root at all.

Comment: Yes, a private repository for each user (somewhere in their `$HOME`) is _definitely_ the way to go here. You don't want developers stepping on each other's toes in a single source directory!

Comment: Thanks! We actually are using git, on multiple machines. However, each machine needs to deploy the application in a directory accessible by multiple users, most importantly by the php user. We could keep copies of the source in each person's /home and deploy the application from there, but that would add an unnecessary step to testing. Plus in the case of python, the source code is the same as the application anyway. It's easier to just keep one repository on each machine in a place accessible by multiple users.

Comment: I think this is being slightly confused by the fact that the deployment and the source appear to be the same. IMO, developers should always work on their own copy of the repository and then push up to a shared repo as required. This shared repo could be on GitHub (or similar) or it could be in `/var`, or it could even be the deployment in `/usr/local`, `/opt` or `/var/www` or wherever. The key point is that **no one should be directly working on the shared repo**, as this defeats the point of git.

Answer (score 0):

The answer you refer to discuss about the installation of a program, not the sharing of data between users. No matter if that data turns out to be Excel files, a large collection of movies or source code that is being developed locally, it should never be put anywhere under `/usr`. The same goes for `/opt`.

Directories `/usr`, `/opt` and `/var` all have very well defined usage semantic, defined in a document name the Filesystem Hierarchy Standard (or FHS for short). The latest version is hosted there: http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html. Respecting this semantic is important because your operating system (or to be more specific, several programs included in your Linux distribution, as well as other programs you may install by yourself) have specific behaviour regarding the usage of these directories. For example, if you create a subdirectory under `/usr/share`
and it turns out that the name of that directory conflict with the name of a program you try to install at a latter time, then it is possible that the installer overwrites, alters, renames or deletes the content of that directory. If it makes thing easier to put in perspective, consider that putting your team's data files under `/usr` or `/opt` would be comparable to storing them under `C:\Windows\` or `C:\Program Files` on a Windows-based computer.

One thing to note is that the FHS *addresses issues where file placements need to be coordinated between multiple parties such as local sites, distributions, applications, documentation, etc*. The FHS doesn't try to set rules for every single situation you may have: *local placement of local files is a local issue* (FHS, section 1.1).

So back to your original question, let's consider a few acceptable options:

- `/home/<projectname>` or `/home/<someprefix>/<projectname>` — The FHS says: *`/home` is a fairly standard concept, but it is clearly a site-specific filesystem*. There is absolutely no requirement that every directory under `/home` be the name of an actual user; creating subdirectories for groups or projects is therefore acceptable, though doing so requires some manual precautions to avoid eventual conflicts, should a new user be created whose name match the name of an existing project.
- `/srv/<projectname>` or `/srv/<someprefix>/<projectname>` — According to the FHS, *`/srv` contains site-specific data which is served by this system*. The FHS then goes on explaining that *the methodology used to name subdirectories of /srv is unspecified*, and gives an example including `/srv/compsci/cvs` (that is most probably the CVS repository itself for the *compsci* working group). From my personal experience, most administrators that exploit the `/srv` directory
  goes on with a per-client, per-site or per-project subdirectory (or sometime, a per-client then a per-project subdirectories), and then put data directories at that level.
- `/<someprefix>/<projectname>` or `/media/<volumename>/<someprefix><projectname>` — I honestly don't know why this option is rarely mentionned in the Linux world, but let's make this clear: this is really *your* system, and the FHS says that you are free to create new directories at the root level as long as you do not conflict with anything for which has well-established semantic. You could for example create a directory `/projects` or `/team` and organize files in these as you see fit. I know that some administrators prefer to have these somewhat isolated from the rest of the filesystem, so mount a distinct volume (under `/media/volumename`). Back to the Windows analogy, that would be similar to creating a new directory directly under `C:\` or to setup a distinct volume, say `D:\`; both strategies should sound *acceptable* to most administrators (though with varying preferences toward one or another of these options).

As for myself, my preference goes toward a `/srv/<client>/<project>/` structure on all my business servers, because it makes it easy to collocate all services of a given project. Inside one of these directory, I will generally have both service-oriented and functional-oriented subdirectories; for example, I may have `etc`, `htdocs`, `logs`, `git`... The `git` directory is itself subdivided on the name of the git repository (that is, I may have multiple git repositories for a project).